# How to enable Deep Link in Android Studio Web View App?

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio, android-webview

I have an app made by an app developer with the following code in the app.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NpqO.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quyBz.png)

I do have the app source code if needed.

What to I need to do with the app or which code do I need to add to my website to open the app whenever the user visits my website automatically?

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code! See how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create URL prefixes from Firebase Console

**example**

> exampleapp.page.link

this is your link look like this

```
https://exampleapp.page.link/?link=https://www.exampleapp.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibn=com.example.ios
```

just replace these according to your app

```
https://**youfirebaseprefix**.page.link/?link=https://www.**youfirebaseprefix**.com/&apn=**you app package id**&ibn=com.example.ios
```

the resulting link is the final link you can use this on your website to open or download your app